# Sorting php array by 2 custom order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, usort

What is the best way to sort a php array using 2 custom sequential ordering:

```
$valueOrder = array('dev1', 'com', 'check', 'data');
$titleOrder = array('title4', 'title7', 'title3', 'title9');
$array = array(
    array('value' => 'com', 'title' => 'title7'),
    array('value' => 'dev1', 'title' => 'title9'),
    array('value' => 'dev1', 'title' => 'title7'),
    array('value' => 'data', 'title' => 'title4'),
);
```

I like this solution but it works only for one custome order :

```
usort($array, function ($a, $b) use ($valueOrder) {
    $pos_a = array_search($a['value'], $valueOrder);
    $pos_b = array_search($b['value'], $valueOrder);
    return $pos_a - $pos_b;
});

var_dump($array);
```

it's possible to use the same solution using $valueOrder and $titleOrder ???

Comment: Do you want to sort by value then, if two items have the same value to reorder them after title?

Comment: yes , exactly  if two items have the same value reorder them after title

Answer (score 0):

In the user defined custom sort function, you compare the items by value and if that value is the same, then compare by label. But, you should be aware that `array_search` returns `FALSE` in case the needle is not found so arithmetic operations will not distinguish `FALSE` from `ZERO`.

```
usort($array, function ($a, $b) use ($valueOrder, $titleOrder) {
    $pos_a = search($a['value'], $valueOrder);
    $pos_b = search($b['value'], $valueOrder);

    if ($pos_a === $pos_b) {
        return search($a['title'], $titleOrder) - search($b['title'], $titleOrder);
    }
    return $pos_a - $pos_b;
});


//just like array_search but more friendly to comparison
function search($needle, $heystack)
{
    $pos = array_search($needle, $heystack);

    if (false === $pos) {
        return PHP_INT_MAX;
    }

    return $pos;
}
```

Comment: @devlogi I had a typo. Please try again.